# Azure Function, delay

Tags: azure, azure-functions, powershell-core

I have a CRM system, when a contact is added, I want to add them to an accounting system.

I have setup a webhook in the CRM system that passes the contact to an Azure Function. The Azure function connects to the accounting system API and creates them there.

There is a little other processing I need to do before the user can be added to the accounting system.

I need about a 5 minute delay after receiving the webhook before I can add the user to the accounting system.

I would rather not add a pause or delay statement in the Azure Function as there is a timeout limit, and also It's a consumption plan so I want each function to action quickly.

I am using Powershell core.

Is a Service Bus Queue the best way to do this?

Comment: "need about a 5 minute delay". Sounds to me that you trigger the web hook to fast. Trigger it when all the processing is done

Comment: I have no control over the timing of the webhook, it's triggered by the CRM immediately when the contact is added by an inbuilt function in the CRM

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Timer in a Durable Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers?tabs=csharp) for this. Then you won't need an extra component like a queue. A [Durable Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) is all you need. For example (warning: not compiled this):

Note: Durable Functions [do support powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-powershell-vscode) but I don't ;-) So the code below is to understand the concept.

```cs
[FunctionName("Orchestration_HttpStart")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
  [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
  ILogger log)
{
  // Function input comes from the request content.
  string content = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Orchestration", content);

  log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
  return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
}

[FunctionName("Orchestration")]
public static async Task Run(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var requestContent = context.GetInput<string>();

    DateTime waitAWhile = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    await context.CreateTimer(waitAWhile, CancellationToken.None);
    await context.CallActivityAsync("ProcessEvent", requestContent);
}

[FunctionName("ProcessEvent")]
public static string ProcessEvent([ActivityTrigger] string requestContent, ILogger log)
{
  // Do something here with requestContent

  return "Done!";
}
```

> I would rather not add a pause or delay statement in the Azure Function as there is a timeout limit, and also It's a consumption plan so I want each function to action quickly.

The 5 minutes delay introduced by the timer won't count as active time so you won't run out of time on the consumption plan for those minutes.

Comment: I must use powershell, the 'API' for the Accounting system is based on a Powershell module that I need to load to interact.

Comment: @user3565039 well, as I stated you can do it using powershell. The code in my answer is based on c# but does show how such a durable function with a timer conceptually works.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a Service Bus Queue the best way to do this?

You can use it, but Azure Storage Queue is cheaper for your scenario.

What you can do is create a time triggered functions (* */5 * * * *) and will check for a message in a queue. If the time between the execution and the time the message was created is greater than  minutes, then you process and complete the message, otherwise, don't complete the message and it will return to the queue for the next execution.